# How To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error :

"State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument.To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect(). "

Here is the code -->

```
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
  const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState(true);
     useEffect(() => {
        const addListeners = () => {
          let loadChannels = [];
          channelRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
            loadChannels.push(snap.val());
            setChannels(loadChannels, () => {
              setFirstChannel();
            });
          });
        };
        addListeners();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, []);
      const setFirstChannel = () => {
        const channel = channels[0];
        if (firstLoad && channels.length > 0) {
          setCurrentChannel(channel);
          setFirstLoad(false);
        }
      };
```

Initially in redux, currentChannel is showing null.
I want if there is a channel,then the currentChannel should be the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback as your first parameter to your useEffect and pass loadChannels to your side-effect

```
const setFirstChannel = (channels) => {
      const channel = channels[0];
      if (firstLoad && channels.length > 0) {
          setCurrentChannel(channel);
          setFirstLoad(false);
      }
};

 useEffect(() => {
        const addListeners = () => {
          let loadChannels = [];
          channelRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
            loadChannels.push(snap.val());
            setChannels(prevState => {
              setFirstChannel(loadChannels); 
              return loadChannels;
            });
          });
        };
        addListeners();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, []);
```